# Apache FOP missing glyphs after exchanging FOP 1.1 for FOP 1.0

Tags: java, apache, pdf, fonts, apache-fop

I was successful transforming XML to PDF using Apache FOP 1.1 embedded in a Java application. Unfortunately, I've been instructed to downgrade to FOP 1.0 in order to comply with company licencing. So, I replaced the 1.0 jar with the 1.1 jar, and cross checked the dependency jars for compatibility. Everything builds ok, and the program runs fine. However, the FOP 1.0 generated PDF only contains "#" for every character with the error:

```
Glyph "M" (0x4d, M) not available in font "Helvetica".
```

(Here, "M" is only used as an example. But it shows this error for every character in the file.) I have looked up this error on the Apache site, which states:

```
If no glyph can be found for a given character, FOP will issue a warning and use the glpyh for "#" (if available) instead.
```

I find this strange since this code worked fine for FOP 1.1 and I am using basic alphanumeric characters. (i.e. even "Hello World" doesn't print correctly"). My code for the transformation is based on the example from the Apache site, and it's fairly straightforward

```
//Constructs a fop with desired output format and user settings
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", agent, out);

//Setup JAXP using identity transformer direct from XSLT:FO output template
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslfoReceiptLayout))); // identity transformer

//Setup input stream from XML string
Source src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(receiptXml));

//Resulting SAX events msut be piped through to FOP
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

//Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
transformer.transform(src, res);

logger.debug("Finished XML to PDF conversion");
```

Where *xslfoReceiptLayout* is a string containing my xslfo data. I have tried simplifying this data to the example from the W3 site, to the same effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
    <fo:region-body />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block>Hello W3Schools</fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Manually config font using a config file to auto detect system fonts
- Set font base directory to the system font directory
- Setting different fonts for font-family values in the xsl:fo

I'm not clear on what I'm missing. I've been scouring the Apache site and google for changes between FOP 1.0 and FOP 1.1 that would be relative to this, but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I located a precompiled version of the FOP 1.0 jar from our company's asset manager site, and it seems to have fixed the problem. Not sure where my 1.0 build from the source taken from the Apache site went wrong. My best guess would be that the precompiled version contained self-contained fonts which the Apache source didn't have.